# Set choices in Symfony FormType class

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm creating a form in Symfony2. The form has a field which is mapped to an entity array like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('card', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Card',
        'property' => 'description',
        'choices' => $choices
    ));
```

I load the $choices array in my Controller. If I create the Form using the FormBuilder in the Controller I can use easily set the choices option, but I'd like to keep it in its own class to avoid bloating the Controller. Is there a clean way to inject the $choices array when creating the form?

Comment: Well, using `$options` is the clean way, but indeed not the automatic way. It actually depends on what your `$choices` are. Are they the result of a query (in that case you can use the `query_builder` option in your entity field), a constant array (in that case, just create a private attribute in your `FormType`), or something data-dependant?

Comment: Which version of symfony are you using ?

Comment: I'm working on a project using Symfony 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best way, and it does seem a bit over-engineered, but I ended up defining the form as a service like this:

```
my_custom_form_service:
    class: AppBundle\Form\MyFormType
    calls:
        - [ setUser, ["@security.context"] ]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: my_form }
```

I needed the user object because I obtain the choices array from that entity.

Comment: I just answered to propose some alternatives.